# ASP.NET Core sequential restart in IIS during app pool recycle

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, application-pool

I got an ASP.NET Core application which uses file based queues.

The running process (the app) must have exclusive write access to the files. I'm using `IApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping` to be able to detect the shutdown and close the files. That normally works fine.

However, each time IIS recycles the application pool it first starts a new process and then, after a while, kills the old process. That hinders the new process from getting exclusive write access.

I thought that I had solved that by allowing the new process to keep retrying to open the files during a limited time period. However, today it took approximately 40 seconds before the old process was shutdown.

I can of course keep increasing the retry-timer, but is wondering if there are a better way to deal with this issue?

Comment: It is a bad idea to use such file based queues when you already know IIS enables overlapping rotation by default. But you can turn that off, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/recycling/#configuration

Comment: But why is it taking 40 seconds and sometimes longer to shutdown the process? Most of my requests just takes at most one second to respond to.  There is no reason to linger that long.

Comment: That can be answered by several approaches (like taking several dumps during that 40 seconds and analyze the activities, or using a profiler). There must be a reason.